# How do I use Java's 3D library?

Tags: java, 3d, drawing

My question has two parts. First, how do I use Java's 3D library from a development persperctive?

Do I only program with Java's 3D API? Do I need any other APIs/libraries?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.4.0_01-oth-JPR

Second, how does the end user run my Java 3D application? Do they just install the Java 3D library?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR

Do they need any other libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Java3D is just one of many competing 3D frameworks for Java. I think probably the most popular is JOGL, which is a very thin wrapper over OpenGL and therefore has the advantage that if you are familiar with OpenGL there is not much new to learn in order to do the same things in Java. For games, LWJGL is also popular.

All the various 3D libraries can be distributed along with your application, or can package an installer for the library along with your installer.

Comment: But if I'm using Java 3D, do I need both "Java 3D API" and "Java 3D" libaries? I'm confused wy there are two similar libraries for downlaoding?

Comment: I would assume that the API is just the documentation, and the library is the actual code. You probably want to download both and tell your IDE to use the API file when displaying javadoc for the library.